# Negative lookahead Regex Issue

Tags: regex

I started looking lookaheads and tried to create a simple example, but for some reason it's not working properly when I try using negative lookahead.

I have the following simple regex:

`href="(.+?)"(?!\s)`

and this string:

```
<a href="test.com">test</a> 
<a href="test.com" title="title">test</a>
```

Testing enviorment: https://regex101.com/r/JztPUe/1

I'm trying to take the url beween the href only if it's not followed by a space, but it seems that it doesn't undestand me, since it's getting the first and the second URL.

When I change it to a positive lookahead it's working as it should be and it takes only the second URL, but the negative one is not working as expected.

Can someone point where is my mistake?

Comment: This is a prime example of why regex is fundamentally unfit for any kind of parsing.

Comment: Even though `.+?` is lazy, it will still expand until it an find a match. You could either turn `"(.+?)"` into an atomic group `(?>"(.+?)")` or use a negated character class `[^"]+` to avoid the expansion over the space. But basically you shouldn't parse HTML with regex, except when you have a very well defined piece of html.

Comment: @Siguza thanks for the comment. I won't be using it for any parsing (for now at least). I'm just trying to understand how lookaheads works, but since my example is not working correctly then it seems that my understanding at the moment is wrong.

Comment: I agree with @Siguza. Just for an example: https://regex101.com/r/JztPUe/4

Comment: @Sebastian Proske and @hek2mgl thank you for the comments. I will refrain from using `.+` so often and target it more specifically. As for the string I'm using, this was the first thing that it came to mind when I was thinking to add a sample string, no specific reason that it was HTML. :)

Comment: @SebastianProske I might go further and say that regex should never be used to parse HTML, because HTML has a habit of having nested (irregular) content.  In this simple case, we can give an answer with a caveat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using an HTML parser instead of trying to do this with a regex.  That being said, you could just phrase your regex by insisting that what follows the `href` clause is not a space:

```
href="([^"]*)"[^ ]
```

## Demo

Your current regex:

```
href="(.+?)"(?!\s)
```

works as expected in Regex 101 when slightly rewritten as this:

```
href="([^"]*)"(?!\s)
```

## Demo

The issue you were having appears to be caused by the flavor of regex in your demo not supporting the lazy dot `(.+?)`.  This is a Perl extension and is not supported by all engines.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You are fundametally correct and it work if it's done that way, but the issue is not that I don't know how to tartget the href properly, but that I'm trying to understand how it's failing on me using the lookahead. :) ( I would give you a +1 but I need 15 rep for this )

Comment: @Noobie The problem is that you lookahead but you never match anything.

Comment: I tried you last example here https://regex101.com/r/JztPUe/5 but it seems that problem still do persist. I did try to add the title in the lookahead `\stitle` but the issue is still the same.

Comment: @Noobie The problem is the flavor of regex being used in the demo, which does not support lazy dot.

Comment: Actually not related to any lack of matching chars after the lookahead (a lookahead as ending pattern is totally legal and functional).

Comment: with that regex a `<link href=` will be matched too though

Comment: @Thielicious No it won't.  The "smallest" match would be `href=""X` where `X` is any non space character.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, you don't understand. this will match the href of a link tag whether space or not. best is just add `a\s` in front it narow it down to anchors only.

Comment: @PJProudhon You're right, I just checked.  The issue is that lazy dot does not seem to be supported in the demo, making it appear that other things are not working correctly.

Comment: @Thielicious I got you now...well as has been said an HTML parser is the way to go in most cases.  A regex simply isn't well suited to HTML/XML content.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen haha but nearly, and it is much more challenging

Comment: Lazy dot also working as it is supposed to. Even lazy, if a match is possible, it will match. Problem is still related with the negative lookahead: `href="(.+?)"(?!\s)` = match up to a `"` not followed by a spacing character. In second example, the third `"` matches exactly that. Still correct also to leave the lazy matching, else it would match up to the fourth occurence of `"`. Your last regex shows what should be done: adding contrast prevent the engine to match a `"` inside a pair.

Answer (score 1):

With space `href="\K(\S+)"\s\K` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8OPQaG/2)

Without space `href="\K(\S+)">\K` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ewptk6)

`\K` escapes string sequences.